# How to keep watchpoint on variables for Javascript development?

Tags: javascript, debugging, watchpoint

I am working on a WebGL project with Javascript and I'm finding it really difficult to trace an error in my code.

In order to debug the program, I'm in **need of a watchpoint** checker, so that I can check when does the faulty variable data getting changed.

Currently I am using Chrome browser, which lacks this feature in development tool. Can someone suggest me some advanced developer toolkit for Javascript debugging that has got watchpoint feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/tips-and-tricks#favorite-expression)

Instead of writing again and again a variable name or an expression you are going to check a lot during a debug session, add it to the ‘Watch Expression’ list. You refresh the values if you modify them directly, or just watch them change while the code runs

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Chrome, you can try the experimental Object.observe():

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe